# How to calculate expiration date based on next record's [EffectiveDate]-1 in T-SQL (SSMS 2017)?

Tags: sql-server, date, calculated-field

I have the following simple query, and the resulting table:

```
    SELECT 
          [Client_ID],
          [ClientName],
          [EffectiveDate],
          [MedConditionID],
          [MedCondition]

    FROM
         [Medications]
```

Resulting Table:

[image]

I need to populate  [ExpirationDate] field - which is based on next record's [EffectiveDate] field - 1.

For example - if effective dates are  '1/16/2019', '10/16/2019' then the [ExpirationDate] for '1/16/2019'= '10/15/2019', etc.

For the biggest effective date (in this table it's '3/18/2020'), expiration date should always be = '2050/12/31'

Please see updated table below (how I need to populate [ExpirationDate], I highlighted the 1st 2 examples):

[image]

Plz, help with any suggestions

I was thinking about some Lag() / Lead() functions that will compare records between each other, but not sure

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @Medications table
(
[Client_ID] int,
[ClientName] varchar(50),
[EffectiveDate] date,
[MedConditionID] int,
[MedCondition] varchar(50)
);


insert into @Medications(Client_Id, ClientName, EffectiveDate, MedConditionId, MedCondition)
values
(100, 'jeffrey', '20190116', 123, 'Alcohol'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20191016', 123, 'Alcohol'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20191016', 267, 'Head'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20191220', 123, 'Alcohol'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20191220', 267, 'Head'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20200121', 123, 'Alcohol'),
(100, 'jeffrey', '20200121', 267, 'Head');


select EffectiveDate, 
    dateadd(day, -1,
    lead(EffectiveDate, 1, '20510101' ) over(partition by Client_id, MedConditionId order by EffectiveDate)
    ) as ExpirationDate,
    *
from @Medications;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and looks like this will work :)